# How to avoid nested LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to create something like a list inside a cardview in a recyclerview.

It is a detail box which should be filled programatically in the getholderview function of the recycler adapter.

Now i came up with the following code, but somehow i get a feeling this is not very performant.

How can i avoid a lot of nested layouts to realize this and should i even try to avoid it in this case?

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        <RelativeLayout ...>
            ... Other content Title
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_loyalty_black_24dp"
            />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cell_textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profileImage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profileImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fat_bar_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profileImage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profileImage"
    android:layout_below="@id/cell_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fett:"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:id="@+id/detailBox"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_below="@id/fat_bar_text"
                          android:gravity="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="Value:"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="500€"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="Test:"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="blah"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The root LinearLayout is unnecessary, use the CardView as the root element.

the second LinearLayout is unnecessary too if you don't have touch event or style on it. replace it with `layout_below` attr in the child element

you can put the innermost LinearLayout which contain two TextView into an another xml file, and include them with `<include>` tags, this can make your code more simple and clean. and easy to reuse. like this

mytext.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Value:"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="500€"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

cardview.xml

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/mytext"
    android:id="@+id/mytext1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<include 
    layout="@layout/mytext"
    android:id="@+id/mytext2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to remove the second two but then the views are not positioned anymore, please see the edited questions.

Comment: I don't understand? Did you set `android:below` in the child view in the second LinearLayout?

Comment: do you mean android:layout_below, studio doesn't give me this option in autocomplete, what id should i set it, the id of the cardview?

Comment: remove the second `LinearLayout`, then set it in the third `LinearLayout`, doesn't this work?

Comment: this would work, but i need the separation for other code, but i like it like it is now thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Please, consider to use [Constraint Layout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1#.jc5ihmy0e). It was created to provide flexibility of building layouts of any complexity. It reduces number of nested layout. [One more link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor)